# Bash regex - different number of backslashes for escaping?

Tags: regex, bash, escaping

Recently I wrote a script with such regex test:

```
# Works fine on Sabayon/Mac, doesn't work on CentOS
[[ $line =~ (.+)\{(.+)\} ]] || continue
```

It runs smoothly on Sabayon Linux and also on Mac, but then I needed to run it on other environment and script failed. It was CentOS Linux. I found out after a while that I need to make double backlash escape to make it work.

```
# Works fine on CentOS, does not on Sabayon/Mac
[[ $line =~ (.+)\\{(.+)\\} ]] || continue
```

Environtment list:

- CentOS release 5.5 (Final), 2.6.18-194.el5, running GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
- Sabayon latest release, 3.12.0-sabayon, running GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- OS X 10.9.3, running GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)

Why is that happening? How to make it run on both environments?

Comment: I don't have a Mac I can test with, could you try: `[[ $line =~ (.+)[{](.+)[}] ]]` That works fine on CentOS.

Comment: Very odd that the difference is between two variations of 3.2, not between 3.2 and 4.2. I suspect a bug that was fixed between 3.2.25 and 3.2.51.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the expression in a variable and use that in your test:

```
re="(.+)\{(.+)\}"
[[ $line =~ $re ]] || continue
```

I don't think you really need the parentheses here. `".+\{.+\}"` would work as well.

Comment: I forgot to say, but I need capture groups, so parentheses are needed. Your solution works fine, but also solution in comment above, by scragar, works well. Thank you both, guys.